# Chartjs in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am new to Django web development.

Originally I used HTML and JavaScript to format and visualize the result which is a list of tuples. It will link to `n` pictures and create `n` canvases for `n` result in `cat_result`.

```
{% if cat_result %}
 <h3>We found {{ count }} result{{ count|pluralize }} </h3>
 {% for res in cat_results %}
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('id', 'pic'+{{res.2}});
//linking to a picture based on res.2
document.body.appendChild(img);
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.setAttribute('id', 'canv'+{{res.2}});
document.body.appendChild(canv);
//a plot using chart.js with values res.3, res4, res.5
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now I am using AJAX to get the data. 
I want to plot using `cat_result[i][8]`,`cat_result[i][9]`,`cat_result[i][10]` inside a loop in AJAX success function, but below did not create canvas or plot on it.

I am not sure how I can have Javascript work with `replaceWith` HTML,or what should I do to incorporate Javascript in ajax success output loop.

```
<form id="cat_select">{% csrf_token %} 
<input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
<input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
  <h2 class="result-box">The result is : <strong id="result"></strong></h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','#cat_select',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/cat_select',
        data:{
            l2:$('#l2').val(),
            l3:$('#l3').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function server_response(response) {
                // convert to json format
                const r = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(r);
                var text=$('<i></i>');
                for (i=0; i<cat_result.length;i++){
                text.append('<id="result">' + cat_result[i][0]+'<br>');
                canvas_and_plot(cat_result[i][8],cat_result[i][9],cat_result[i][10])
               };
                $('#result').replaceWith(text);
}
});

function canvas_and_plot(a,b,c) {
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.width = 200;
canv.height = 200;
canv.setAttribute('id', 'result');
canv.style.position = 'relative';
canv.style.float = 'left';
document.body.appendChild(canv);
var C = document.getElementById(canv.getAttribute('id'));
 if (C.getContext) {              
    if (C.getContext) {
            new Chart(document.getElementById(canv.getAttribute('id')), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["1","2","3"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: ["Count"],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 0.5)",
                        borderColor : "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                        data: [a,b,c] 
                    },
                ]
            },
options: {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
        }
    }]
    }}
  });
}
}
}

</script>
```

How can I plot in loop with ajax success result? Thanks.

Comment: what is the response you are getting, and what is the expected output?

Comment: @iAmADeveloper, I am not quite sure what do you mean by response.But currently raw data are returned within `#result`. The expected output will be like give the length of result (k) first, then have a picture and several plots for the k entries in result.

Comment: I would say, if server returns JSON headers, than you do not need to parse it, or use `dataType: 'json'`. As second, you can store result in jQuery object like `var myResponse = $(r.cat_result)`, than do whatever you want with it, before you finally insert it into dom.

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks. I updated my question after some attempts but now get an error. Can you have a look and advise on what's missing and how I can improve this? Thanks.

Comment: Start with `var text=$('<i></i>')`, than you can use jQuery method append simple as `text.append('<strong id="result">' + cat_result[1]+ '</strong>')`. Please be careful and do not insert same element `id` over and over again - it has to be unique. If you need a unique id (but I doubt you need that id at all), than in your loop you can do `'<strong id="result' + idx + '">'`... better use some class instead.

Comment: Thanks @skobaljic !  That works perfectly for HTML. I also need to use javascript for plotting but am not sure how to make it work. Can you shed some light on this? I have updated my question above. Thanks.